# GVim no longer launches from Unity after customizing .desktop file

Tags: .desktop, gvim

I customized the Exec line in:
`~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=GVim 7.4
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=View and edit text files
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=/usr/local/bin/gvim --remote-silent %F
TryExec=gvim
Icon=gvim
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;Development;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gvim
Keywords=Plaintext;Write;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=gvim
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Now when I open files from Nautilus they open in a single instance of GVim which is the behaviour I desired when I added `--remote-silent`

Now when I click on the GVim icon in the Unity toolbar I get a spinning mouse cursor then nothing.  If I run the command in a terminal GVim opens with a buffer named '%F'

How can I restore the icon behaviour and keep the nautilus behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally settled on using `gvim --remote-silent "" %F` as the command in the .desktop file.

Opening files from Nautilus works as expected, all files open in the same instance of GVim.

Adding the `""` before the parameter allows GVim to open from the Unity launchbar with the following error message.
[image]

This obviously is not perfect but it works for my purposes.